# How does Java servlet handle a URL that ends with '/'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Usually, these two requests:

```
localhost:8080/test
localhost:8080/test/
```

have no difference.

However, when I add a `servlet-mapping` config:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then

```
localhost:8080/test/
```

Does not work, it would return **404** error, I don't understand that I had added a config like this:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/interceptor-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml,
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

So, why would the request not go to this servlet, what is the magic in `*.html`? The others like `*.txt`, `*.jpeg` would not cause this problem.

Comment: beause "localhost:8080/test/" does not match "*.html", or is it an other question?

Comment: actually, I want localhost:8080/test/ match 'rest'

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

leave

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and let Spring distinguish between rest and html requests.

Comment: but I need html requests. My webapps have static html files used by ueditor.